# Can't resolve hostnames using the AmazonProvidedDNS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created a private zone for my internal domain. I've created the necessary `DHCP Options set` and rebooted my server once I set the VPC to use the new dhcp set. If I attempt to ping a record, i get no response. I'm at a lost, what am I missing?

```
dig @172.29.0.2 mymachine.mydomain.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.3 <<>> @172.29.0.2 mymachine.mydomain.net.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 63401
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mymachine.mydomain.net. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.net.   46  IN  SOA ns-1536.awsdns-00.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 40 1800 3600 604800 300

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 172.29.0.2#53(172.29.0.2)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 09 15:20:50 EDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 156
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah verifying DNS lookups. As you can see, running a DIG returns nothing.

Comment: What steps did you in order to configure an internal DNS on Route 53? Did you add the correct VPC, check [this AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is documented, but my observation is that when the `ns-xxxx.awsdns-nn.*` name in the SOA has an `xxxx` value divisible by 512 (ns-0, ns-512, ns-1024, ns-1536), that suggests that your query *is* being handled by a Route 53 private hosted zone... so this implies that the VPC DNS is correct, and the problem is in the Route 53 config.  Do you have exactly one (not more than one) private hosted zone matching this domain?  Private zones have no mechanism for resolving ambiguous condition where the answer could be found in more than one matching private zone.